# wc -l *.py for all subdirectories

Tags: bash

i'd like to count all lines in all .py files in all subdirectories (and sub-sub-...-directories).
I tried this to:

```
find strats/ -type f | wc -l *.py
```

but again, it only counts the lines in the .py files in the current directory,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
find strats/ -type f -name '*.py' -exec wc -l {} +
```

for individual counts for each file; or

```
find strats/ -type f -name '*.py' -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

for a single aggregate count of lines over all the files.